# WINE mishandles UTF-8 when reading file in CUI app

Tags: utf-8, wine

A simple CUI application (MITLM) reads in a text file and outputs a text file. It wasn't written with Unicode in mind, but handles UTF-8 just fine (because that's the beauty of UTF-8). However, when run under WINE, non-ASCII characters get messed up. What could be the reason for this? Since MITLM is open source I've re-compiled it for Linux and it works fine, but I'm still curious.